# How to know what modules were included into a class

Tags: ruby, module, metaprogramming

I want to find what modules were included into a specific class, excluding its ancestors. E.g.:

```
module M; end
module N; end

class A; include M; end
class B < A; include N; end

p B.included_modules

#=> [N, M, Kernel]
# I want only N
```

I can't use `B.included_modules[0]` since I don't know how many modules `B` includes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know A is the superclass of B then

`p B.included_modules - A.included_modules` should give you what you are looking for else

`p B.included_modules - B.superclass.included_modules`

```
module M; end
module N; end
module O; end

class A; include M; end
class B < A; include N; include O; end

p B.included_modules - A.included_modules
#=> [O, N]
```

Comment: Or `p B.included_modules - B.superclass.included_modules` :)